# connecting an android phone to a pc to via usb to share internet connection

Tags: networking

I used to connect my Android phone to my computer using a USB cable to connect to the internet. But today as I tried to reconnect, this is what it says:

> An error occurred when internet connection sharing was being enabled. 
>   The service cannot be started, either because it has no enabled device associated with it.

But I'm real sure that my device is properly enabled. I think the problem here is that I need to have the admin access.

What should I do?

Comment: You can always [enable the Administrator account](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/enable-the-hidden-administrator-account-on-windows-vista/) temporarily in Windows and log in into it to see for your needs.

Comment: i am now using the admin account. but i still cant connect

Answer (score 0):

If it worked in the past without admin access, it's unlikely you would suddenly need admin access, It's more likely that the android device needs to be restarted, a possible bad USB port, or a system update that has changed something. First try powering the phone down and rebooting it. If it continues to fail, you can attempt to remove and re-install the app or module(service). If there have been any updates the phone recently, that could also cause a service, app, or module to suddenly fail due to changes in compatibility of the system code.
It may also be the USB port starting to fail. The connectors are not designed for continuous plugging and unplugging everyday. Over time, the connector will become lose and fail to connect anymore.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Does the phone communicate at all with the computer? Can you transfer music or photos to it/from it. I'm suspecting it may be the usb connector on the phone or re-installing the software and android phone drivers.

Comment: It would help to know the type of phone, the carrier, and the version of Android as well.